# Receiving Errno 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) on Ajax calls in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

There's been pretty much of discussion on this topic, and still the peculiarity of my question is that I am using `beforeSend`, and I blame the error on my possibly incorrect usage of this operator.

So I have this JS code:

```
DATA_LIST_REQUEST = $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:"/ajax_refresh_order_suggestions/",
        beforeSend : function()
        {           
            if(DATA_LIST_REQUEST != null)
                DATA_LIST_REQUEST.abort();
        },
        data:data,  
        success: function(response) 
        {
            refresh_zeon_data_table(response, $table);
        }
    });
```

And the respective Django view which has nothing special in its code, so I don't post it to keep the question concise (will provide it on request).
The above code is called every time the user changes combobox. And sometimes - NOT ALWAYS - I get this unpleasant `error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` error which most interestingly does not lead to fatal error behaviour, I still receive an answer, but it takes me 8 or 9 seconds instead of otherwise instant response.

Am I doing something wrong in the above-mentioned JS code ?

Here's the full traceback

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 61839)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 99, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
[31/Oct/2016 01:27:29] "GET /ajax_refresh_order_suggestions/?q=&legal_entity_own_id=5398&vendors=%5B%5D&merchandise=%5B%5D&positive_chosen_quantity_filter=true&zero_chosen_quantity_filter=true&suggested_equal_to_chosen=true&suggested_less_than_chosen=true&suggested_greater_than_chosen=true HTTP/1.1" 200 46
```

Comment: Receiving the same error, any luck ?

Comment: I upgraded to python 3, and the error is gone now